# Encapsulating Certain Parts of List

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a procedure that "encapsulates" (i.e. puts in a list) elements of a list between a "separator" element.

```
(my-proc '(1 + 2))
=> ((1) (2))

(my-proc '(x * y + z ^ 2 + 1 + 5))
=> ((x * y) (z ^ 2) (1) (5))

(my-proc '((x + 1) * y + 5))
=> (((x + 1) * y) (5))
```

In this case the procedure can be hard-coded to define the + symbol as the separator.

Assume that foldr (fold right operation) is defined, I'd prefer that it'd be in terms of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not giving a full solution since this looks really homework-y.

```
(define (split-expr expr)
   (foldr (lambda (e es)
                  (if (eq? e '+)
                      <???>    ; do split
                      (cons (cons e (car es))
                            (cdr es))))
          <???>    ; what should start be?
          es))
```

Comment: +1 for the right approach, but I'm going to edit your answer to add `<???>` to indicate something to fill in. The comments on their own (without the placeholders) were really confusing. (I actually implemented the complete solution myself, of course.)

Comment: I'm confused. start obviously can't be '(), because the operation calls on (car es) and (cdr es), but I'm not seeing what else it could be. Even then, I have no idea what the alternative clause of the if statement is supposed to accomplish, e,g, given e is 1 and es is (2 3), the result would be ((1 . 2) 3). Could you provide a little more hints please?

Comment: Well it can't be `'()` you're right, but what about `'( () )`

Comment: Thanks, I got it after that. But damn, just when I thought I was getting used to Scheme even something as simple as this gets beyond me without help.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a version in [continuation-passing style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544127/why-continuation-passing-style) (no `foldr`, probably not suitable as a homework answer):

```
(define split/cps
  (λ (sep ls)
    (let loop ([ls ls] [k (λ (item acc)
                               (if item (cons item acc) acc))])
      (cond
        [(null? ls)
          (k #f '())]
        [(eq? sep (car ls))
          (loop (cdr ls)
                (λ (item acc)
                  (k #f (if item (cons item acc) acc))))]
        [else
          (loop (cdr ls)
                (λ (item acc)
                  (k (if item
                         (cons (car ls) item)
                         (list (car ls)))
                     acc)))]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, also without `foldr`:

```
(define split/values
  (λ (sep ls)
    (let loop ([ls ls])
      (cond
        [(null? ls)
          '()]
        [else
          (let-values ([(a d) (car-to-sep sep ls)])
            (if (null? a)
                (loop d)
                (cons a (loop d))))]))))

(define car-to-sep
  (λ (sep ls)
    (let loop ([ls ls] [a '()])
      (cond
        [(null? ls)
          (values '() '())]
        [(eq? sep (car ls))
          (values '() (cdr ls))]
        [else
          (let-values ([(a d) (loop (cdr ls) a)])
            (values (cons (car ls) a) d))]))))
```